# OAuth Authorization code could not be properly fetched

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

[Oauth Authorization Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EijmB.png)

[image]
The code parameter in the queryString contains a "#", which cannot be
obtained via request.getParameter. This is causing a problem in the
subsequent accesstoken token request as iam getting a invalid_code
error.

Comment: This is how the authentication server works it returns the code in the title of the page and part of the body its your job to get it out.

Comment: The way I see it, the `code` parameter ends with `Y`. The `#` is not part of the code parameter.